# Can I use a super class to push to a new view controller which is also inherited?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I have two super view controllers `MasterCategoryListViewController` and `MasterCategoryItemViewController`.

I want to use these in several apps.

I inherit from both of these

```
class CustomListController: MasterCategoryListViewController
class CustomItemController: MasterCategoryItemViewController
```

Now in the `MasterCategoryListViewController`

I have a button handler...

```
@objc open func btnAddTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let itemViewController = MasterCategoryItemViewController()
    itemViewController.title = "Type"
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(itemViewController, animated: true)
}
```

I know I can override the method to push to `CustomItemController` however, I'm just wondering if I can do this in my `MasterCategoryListViewController`, obviously without it knowing anything about what `CustomItemController`?

Comment: Hmmm, must be able to use delegation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method on the parent called something like `detailVCClass()`, answering the class that should be instantiated upon button tap.  The parent can answer something generic, and the subclasses answer any class that's appropriate for each to know about.

Have the button tap method instantiate an instance of `self.detailVCClass()`, rather than a class name literal.

Answer (score 0):

> however, I'm just wondering if I can do this in my
>   MasterCategoryListViewController, obviously without it knowing
>   anything about what CustomItemController ?

Yes. Why not? However, the one that will be pushed is the `MasterCategoryItemViewController`, not any subclassing classes of it. So like what you've mentioned in your question, you know that `btnAddTapped` can be overriden, so do it like that.

OR, you could do something a bit more interesting:

In your `MasterCategoryListViewController`, have an object of `MasterCategoryItemViewController`. Then in your `CustomListController`, apply any subclassing `MasterCategoryListViewController` class. Next, push that `MasterCategoryItemViewController` object in your `btnAddTapped()`

Complete sample:

```
import UIKit

class ListVC: MasterListVC {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = "ListVC"
        self.itemVCToBePushed = ItemVC2()
    }
}

class MasterListVC: UIViewController {

    var itemVCToBePushed: MasterItemVC?

    lazy var button: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 250.0, height: 44.0)
        button.setTitle("Test", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.pushMe), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.backgroundColor = .gray
        return button
    }()

    @objc func pushMe() {
        guard let itemVCToBePushed = self.itemVCToBePushed else { return }
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(itemVCToBePushed, animated: true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = "MasterListVC"
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white

        self.view.addSubview(self.button)
    }
}

/////

class ItemVC: MasterItemVC {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = "ItemVC"
    }
}

class ItemVC2: MasterItemVC {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = "ItemVC2"
    }
}

class MasterItemVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = "MasterItemVC"
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}
```